# vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: tarima.trabajo is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo la siguiente vista la cual deberia de funcionar el filtro con una propiedad computada pero no logro que me funcione me marca el siguiente error

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError:
>   tarima.trabajo is not a function"

La vista es la siguiente:

```
<template>
      <input type="text" v-model="filtrarTarima">
    <div v-for="(tarima, id) in filtrar" :key="id">
      {{ tarima.tarima}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
data() {
return {
filtrarTarima: '',
      tarimas: [
        {
          id: 1,
          tarima: 19347,
          trabajo: 195288,
          parte: "A006287",
          cantidad: 237,
          maquina: "MINILINE 618",
          ubicacion: "ALM05"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          tarima: 19348,
          trabajo: 195289,
          parte: "A006288",
          cantidad: 236,
          maquina: "MINILINE 618",
          ubicacion: "ALM05"
        }
      ],
}
},
computed: { 
     filtrar: function() {
      return this.tarimas.filter((tarima) => tarima.trabajo.includes(this.filtrarTarima));
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Pero el filtro no funciona, me podrian ayudar por favor

Comment: es tarima por que estoy iterando

Comment: si si ahi lo vi.. por eso lo borre.. pero includes se usa con array y trabajo es un dato simple.. o estoy confundido?

Comment: he probado sin el includes, no tengo idea solo lo vi en un tutorial pero con o sin el includes no logro que funcione

Comment: tarima.trabajo == al filtro no anda? no filtra o tira error...

Comment: `includes` es un método que existe en tipos de datos que son strings y arrays, en tu caso es un número. Por eso da error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dijeron, no existe tal cosa como `Number.prototype.includes`. Se maneja casteando a String:

```
String(tarima.trabajo).includes(...)
```

@gbianchi fíjate que el input permite filtrar. Si tienes muchas tarimas esto sí es útil

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        filtrarTarima: '',
        tarimas: [
          {id:1, tarima: 19347,trabajo: 195288},
          {id: 2, tarima: 19348,trabajo: 195289}
        ],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      filtrar: function() {
        return this.tarimas.filter(
           tarima => String(tarima.trabajo)
                        .includes(this.filtrarTarima)
        );
      }
    }
  });

};
```

```css
#app {
padding:0.5em;
}
#app > div {
 margin:0.2em;
}
#app input {
 border-radius:3px;
 margin:  0.2em 0;
 padding:0.4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="filtrarTarima">
  <div v-for="(tarima, id) in filtrar" :key="id">
    {{ tarima.tarima}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Te recomiendo que las propiedades computadas describan mejor lo que significan (e.g. 'tarimasFiltradas').

Un verbo como `filter` es más intuitivo que sea un método. Esto es sólo un comentario

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando el método `includes()` el cual va a:

> Buscar si un elemento existe un una matriz, de ser así regresa `true` y en caso contrario retorna `false`

Para este caso algunas de las claves de tus objetos no almacenan cadenas de textos, por lo tanto los valores numéricos no son iterables.

Por ejemplo:

```
let numero = 12345
console.log(numero[1])
```

Da como resultado:

> UNDEFINED

Mientras que si declaras ese mismo valor numérico entre comillas de esta forma:

```
let numero = "12345"
console.log(numero[1])
```

Da como resultado:

> "2"

Entonces pudieras tener como opciones:

**USA OTRA CLAVE PARA FILTRAR**

Puedes tomar cualquier clave que almacene un *string* para filtrar así:

```
filtrar() {
          return this.tarimas.filter(tarima => tarima.ubicacion.includes(this.filtrarTarima))
}
```

**CAMBIA EL VALOR ORIGINAL**

Es decir aquellas claves que tienen valores que originalmente son numéricos, puedes modificarlos al colocarlos entre comillas y de esta forma volverlos iterables; de modo que el método `includes()` pueda llevar a cabo su trabajo sobre dicho elemento.

incluso con que el valor asociado a la clave que originalmente esta declarado como número quede entre comillas, no importa si el argumento pasado al método `includes()` llega con su formato original igual funcionará:

```js
    let valores = [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "one"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "two"
      }
    ]
    
    let resultado = valores.filter(elemento => elemento.id.includes(1))
    
    console.log(resultado)
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Método **`includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes)

Comment: no entiendo porque tiene que usar includes y no simplemente comparar los valores.. por lo que se ve, va siempre al mismo campo...

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón solo traté de responder al respecto sin embargo es cierto con comparar debería alcanzar